# Remove numbers from all files names in a folder

Tags: python, file, directory, rename

I am trying to remove all numbers from all filenames for files in a folder:

```
import os
import re
infolder = r'E:/folder/test'
def file_rename():
    name_list=os.listdir(infolder)
    print(name_list)
    saved_path=os.getcwd()
    print("Current working directory is"+saved_path)
    os.chdir(infolder)

    for file_name in name_list:
        print("old name"+file_name)
        print("new name"+re.sub('[0-9]', '', file_name))
        os.renames(file_name,file_name.strip("0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)

file_rename()
```

It's correctly printing the new filenames but is not actually changing the files names in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you are printing something different to what you are actually doing.

```py
print("new name"+re.sub('[0-9]', '', file_name))
```

If this is printing the correct content, then your `os.renames` function should look as follows

```py
os.renames(file_name,re.sub('[0-9]', '', file_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip()` function removes leading and trailing characters only.

try using

```
os.renames(file_name, re.sub('[0-9]', '', file_name))
```

instead.